# Inconsistent Spacing Between Separate Equations

Tags: spacing, equations

I just got some behavior I didn't expect for the spacing between equations; I think it's best explained through an MWE, which I put below.

The question is: what is the reason for this?

LaTeX, as far as I know, does most things, including spacing, for a reason, usually in an attempt to optimize the page layout according to its interpretation of the user's input. So I was wondering what the reason behind this choice is, so that I can better understand why I should leave it as is or if/why/how I should override it in some situations.

PS: I know about the `align` environment, and indeed, it doesn't have this issue; this question, however, is more about curiosity than trying to solve a specific problem.

PS2: If I add linebreaks or `\par`s after each `\[a\]` I also get consistent (though more generous) spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent These equations have inconsistent spacing if this line ``pushes down the first.''
\[a\]
\[a\]
\[a\]

\noindent These have inconsistent spacing, regardless of the length of this sentence.\par
\[a\]
\[a\]
\[a\]

\noindent These have consistent spacing, regardless of the length of this sentence.\\
\[a\] 
\[a\]
\[a\]

\end{document}
```

[image: annotated screenshot of output]

Comment: never use display math at the start of a paragraph or after another display math. Use a multi-line display such as `gather`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know that! Is this spacing issue part of the reason, or are there also other reasons for it?

Comment: this is exactly the reason: You are seeing the difference between `\abovedisplayskip`  (used for long lines) and `\abovedisplayshortskip` used for short lines including the spurious empty paragraphs formed by the mis-placed display math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aah, I see, that makes sense now. Thank you! (If you post this as an answer I'll readily accept it of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this example shows you should use a multi-line display such as `gather` and never one display math following another or at the start of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth=3

\begin{document}

\noindent These equations have inconsistent spacing if this line ``pushes down the first.''
\[a\]
\[a\]
\[a\]

\noindent These have inconsistent spacing, regardless of the length of this sentence.\par
\[a\]
\[a\]
\[a\]

\noindent These have consistent spacing, regardless of the length of this sentence.\\
\[a\] 
\[a\]
\[a\]

\end{document}
```

produces

```
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 4.19391fil []
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.75002
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 24.22176fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 122.9979fil []
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 32.55511fil []
...\penalty 200
...\glue(\baselineskip) 10.05556
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0 []
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.28589, shifted 169.85706, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

So you see that unlike adjacent display environment such as `center` that try to merge white space, between later pairs of display you get

```
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
```

so visible space  the sum of the above and below short skips whereas before the second display you either get that or you get

```
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.69446
```

depending on whether the first display uses the display skips or short display skips

Comment: How did you get the second block of code in your answer?

Comment: @steve it's not code it is the log from running your example as amended here with `\showoutput` added

Comment: You should also say that display math should not be preceded by `\par` or a blank line.  Not only will the space before the display be enlarged, but this allows the display to break to a new page when it's at the bottom and there isn't room.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I said that in first comment under the question I'll copy it to the answer:-)